# Open file with registered filetype in a different editor

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

I have a project with *.ts files. 
In one folder these files are TypeScript files. 
In another folder it's TypoScript files.
The filetype *.ts is registered to the TypeScript Editor.
Is it possible to open a *ts file and force it to a different editor? In this case it would be the TypoScript Editor.

The only workaround i see is to rename the TypoScript files to *.tsc or *.t3s.
TypeScript files with the *.ats file ending will not be compiled from the internal TypeScript compiler.

I am using intelliJ 15.

Comment: The file types are a global setting, not something that can be configured per project, so I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I hoped that there is something like in eclipse, where your can rightclick a file and select "open with"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by right click on folder or file by using 'External Tools'
In setting search for External Tools.
then add the editor or application you want open file by adding the location of application or editor
This picture shows how to add  applications

[image: Open file by Atom ide in IntelliJ]

Then right-click on any  file or folder select External Tools then your application