# Is it possible to change the file association for all files under a directory in intelliJ/PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Is it possible to change the file association for all files under a directory?

Example:
The default *.ts is registered for TypeScript.

All *.ts files in the Folder TypoScript is registered for TypoScript.

The pattern /TypoScript/?*.ts does not work.

I am using intelliJ 15.

In another Question i asked if i can select the editor i want to open the file with. This is possible in the eclipse ide. This is also not possible.

Comment: File Types section of the Settings/Preferences is IDE-wide -- it affects ALL projects and not particular folder or even just a project. So the answer is NO (unless, it can be done by some plugin somehow)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open file with registered filetype in a different editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527465/open-file-with-registered-filetype-in-a-different-editor)

Comment: Not really. MY first try was to do it for one project. Now i try to do it IDE-wide. I am searching for a pattern to exclude files in a directory. File based setting the pattern does function. Example: registering the pattern 'constants.txt' to TypoScript will open all constants.txt with the TypoScript Editor. The ? and * are allowed to be used. But maybe not infor directories.

Comment: @kimomat Correct -- that setting works with file name only. I may only suggest to use another file extension (if that's possible, of course); or give such files double extension (e.g. `file.ts.ts` -- in such case `*.ts.ts` has higher priority over `*.ts` and you can assign such pattern to another file type).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no such way. File type associations check only the name of the file, not the directory.